# Exposing Sass file from Meteor package for Meteor App importing

Tags: meteor, sass

I'm working on building a package for meteor 0.9+ that exposes a library off sass mixins called 'Bourbon' and am trying to sort out the best way to provide access to '@import' a stylesheet from the package into a Meteor project.

https://github.com/wolvesio/meteor-bourbon/

Pre Meteor 0.9 this used to be done via something along the lines of:
`@import "packages/wolves:bourbon/bourbon";`

Since the package system changed though this no longer works. Any help as to the best way to do this moving forward would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to use your package, but I get an error: file to import not found or unreadable: "/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/wolves:bourbon/bourbon". I believe the import statement you have in your docs on GitHub may be incorrect. I had to modify it for my IDE to find the file (I use WebStorm). I added the '/' to the beginning and changed 'wolves_bourbon' to 'wolves:bourbon'. Not sure if that needs to be updated in your docs. Please let me know if you need additional information to diagnose the error. I appreciate your help and your work in putting the package together.

Comment: Are you using it from a PC I assume? If so I think it may just be a difference in the file system pathing and I will have to note that in the documentation. Can you do me a favor and open up an issue on the github project with these details so that I can address it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to accomplish what you want, it's a bit hacky but it works at last.

First, you need to add the `.less` files as server assets in your package :

```
Package.onUse(function(api){
  api.addFiles([
    "bourbon/style1.less",
    ...
    "bourbon/styleN.less"
  ],"server",{
    isAsset:true
  });
});
```

Then run `meteor` to trigger the building of your application : this will copy over the server assets to the `.meteor` directory of your application. More precisely, your `.less` files will now live in `".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/wolves:bourbon/bourbon/*"`.

Now you can reference these `.less` files in your application using this super unfriendly path.
I recommend hiding this stuff from your package users by defining an import.less directly in the package :

`packages/wolves:bourbon/bourbon.import.less`

```
@bourbon-root: ".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/wolves:bourbon/bourbon/";

@import "@{bourbon-root}style1.less";
//
@import "@{bourbon-root}styleN.less";
```

Then in the package README, invite your users to simply copy bourbon.import.less in their client directory and reference it from there.

`client/lib/config/style.less`

```
@import "bourbon.import.less";
```

There is one drawback to this approach that I was unable to solve at the moment : the `.less` files are copied in the `.meteor` directory when your application is built (a process that happens when triggering `meteor run`).

However, the build process will try to compile your application `.less` files FIRST, before copying the server assets (in this case our package `.less` files) to the `.meteor` dir.

So the very first time you add the package to an app, it will complain that it is unable to find the package `.less` files, triggering a rebuild (either by killing and relaunching `meteor` or `touch`ing your application `.less` files) will fix this though.